# In PostgreSQL, how can I convert some boolean columns into an array of those, that are true?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this table

```
is_a is_b is_c
t    t    f
f    f    t
f    t    t
...
```

How can I select it into this result?

```
{'a','b'}
{'a','c'}
{'b','c'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the whole row into a JSON, then use a JSON Path query to get only those keys (=columns) that are true:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(to_jsonb(t), '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value == true).key')
from the_table t
```

`to_jsonb(t)` converts the whole row into a JSON value. The JSON Path expression splits that into key/value pairs and then aggregates the keys of the "true" values into an array.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c6884b4fad5281f33c224d8e216b24a9)

---

If you want a native Postgres array, rather than a JSON array, you can do something similar:

```
select t.*, 
       (select array_agg(key) 
       from jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t)) as x(key, value)
       where value = 'true')
from the_table t;
```

This again turns the row into a JSON, then generates one row per key and aggregates that back into a native Postgres array.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=301e5d580a924768ff3b63aac0d05074)

Comment: Whow, that's a bit more complicated, than I had hoped for. Is there a way to convert it into a regular postgres array?

Comment: Well, your desired output looks more like a JSON array, than a native array.

Comment: You are right, I'll fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
  array_agg(k)
from
  (
    values
      ('a', $1.is_a),('b', $1.is_b),('c', $1.is_c)
  ) as letters(k, v)
where
  v;
```

seems to be a possibility, too. No JSON.